# error run Web Farm Framwork 2.2

Tags: web-farm

My server not run web farm framework. It failed as follows:

```
Failed to run operation 'ArrEnableLoadBalancing'.  Filename: \\?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
Error: The configuration section 'system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration.

Failed to run operation 'EnableLoadBalancing'.  Filename: \\?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
Error: The configuration section 'system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration.

Failed to run operation 'Repair'.  Filename: \\?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
Error: The configuration section 'system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration.

Failed to run operation 'AutoRepair'.  Filename: \\?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
Error: The configuration section 'system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration.

Server marked 'Unhealthy' due to failure to run operation 'AutoRepair'
```

help me config error. thanks.